# How to better call app?

Tags: british-english

Sorry, if I mistake with community. But I don't know where I can get help else. Just I need to choose the best app name variant to call reader for reading training.

- Inline Reader
- Stream Reader

The application uses a running line. And I want to mirror it in the app name. I want to emphasize that reading takes place in a single line. But I don't sure which variant is more correct for this purpose.

P.S. English isn't my native language so I cannot choose the best variant.

Comment: To be honest, I suspect picking out a good name for an app is too fiddly a business for ELL to do well. We can certainly get you something that's descriptive (at least, if you give us a few more details in an [edit]), but getting something really worthwhile is a lot tougher.

Comment: No, I understand it, of course. Just I don't sure which variant will be more understandable for English-speaking group.

Comment: Based on your 3rd sentence, "...call reader for reading training...", you mean to improve reading (comprehension + speed, 'supposedly')?

Comment: Yeah, to users can reader their book in single running line and improve their reading speed.

Comment: Just I difficult to judge what the name of the best sounds from the English-speaking.

Comment: Well, in the sphere of marketing, being direct and straightforward might be better. Since this is business, you might want to do some research? (I suggest you do online survey to know which name is 'better' or more preferable)

Comment: I trying to make it :) Just choose first or second variant are better for you. Reason doesn't play role. You will very help me!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a survey asking us to name something, and it's not about English. Answers to this question are very unlikely to help anyone other than the original poster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of those two Inline Reader sounds better, because Stream Reader is very likely to make another impression on the user and they would most probabbly miss the hint. 
I'd suggest something completely different though. In my opinion it will make it more appealing to larger group of people, teenagers and young language learners included. Try the sound of Read-A-Line.

Comment: I like your variant of name!

Comment: You're welcome! I hope it helps.